# How to determine the arc length of ellipse?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, circles, conic-sections

I want to determine the length of an arc from the ellipse in the picture below:

[image]

How can I determine the length of $d$?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the angle arc length of ellipse by knowing angle of it and radius of ellipse?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/432954/how-to-get-the-angle-arc-length-of-ellipse-by-knowing-angle-of-it-and-radius-of)

Comment: This seems (essentially) like a duplicate of the question you asked  before. Please remember that you can edit your questions to add information or ask for more clarification - you don't have to post again.

Comment: You'll need to use an elliptic integral.  See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ellipse.html

Comment: @ZevChonoles Unfortunately did not get something from the previous question. what should I do :(

Comment: @DavidMitra- broken link

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Let $a=3.05,\ b=2.23.$ Then a parametric equation for the ellipse is $x=a\cos t,\ y=b \sin t.$ When $t=0$ the point is at $(a,0)=(3.05,0)$, the starting point of the arc on the ellipse whose length you seek. Now it's important to realize that the parameter $t$ is *not* the central angle, so you need to get the value of $t$ which corresponds to the top end of your arc. At that end you have $y/x=\tan 50$ (degrees). And in terms of $t$ you have $y/x=(b/a)\tan t$. Solving for $t$ then gives
$$t=t_1=\arctan \left( \frac{a}{b}\tan 50 \right).$$

[note I'd suggest using radians here, replacing the $50$ by $5\pi/18.$]

For the arclength use the general formula of integrating $\sqrt{x'^2+y'^2}$ for $t$ in the desired range. In your case $x'=-a \sin t,\ y'=b \cos t$, so that you are integrating
$$\sqrt{a^2 \sin^2t+b^2 \cos^2t}$$
with respect to $t$ from $0$ to the above $t_1$. There not being a simple closed form for the antiderivative (it's an "elliptic integral), the simplest approach now would be to do the integral numerically. This seems the more appropriate in your problem as you only know $a,b$ to two decimals, apparently.

*** When I did this numerically on maple I got about $2.531419$ for the arclength.

Comment: Plus 1 for being frank about the superiority of the numerical approach.

Comment: Thank you coffeemath but I'm having problem with finding _t_

Comment: @MohammadFakhrey I don't know what more to explain. If you could say exactly what is confusing you in my answer, or in the last comment, it might help.

Comment: I did like you said but the result = 2.23042 not 2.531419 ???

Comment: @MohammadFakhrey I just checked it again using 20 digit accuracy for the calculations on maple, and still got $2.5314195...$. Given your answer is so close, maybe maple encountered some numerical error because of the default way it evaluates integrals numerically (I did not use any sophisticated routine like Runge Kutta). On the other hand what software gave your $2.23042$ result? How reliable is it? Anyway there is no independent check beyond using elliptic functions.

Comment: coffeemath Please take a look at this picture (http://s13.postimg.org/co6n64oo7/0000607972816.png) and see if my solution is true or not.

Comment: @MohammadFakhrey, $t$ is an independent parameter going from $0$ to some value $t_1$ such that the a point on the ellipse has coordinates $(a \cos t, b \sin t)$. And no, your solution is incorrect. The angle for each $t$ is $\arctan \left( \frac{b}{a} \tan t \right)$. The solution presented by coffeemath is 100% correct.

Comment: @ja72 how to solve  integral ?

Comment: @MohammadFakhrey, numerically. Google numerical integration and try it.

Comment: @ja72 I want to know if there a software to solve it ?

Comment: Look at related post http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350369/approximating-the-integral-int-00-1-sqrt1-1-2-sin2t-dt

Comment: You can use [Wolfram Alpha](http://wolfr.am/12A6x6u)

Comment: @coffeemath: The solution becomes negative for angles larger than 90 degrees. Can you help me on this?

Comment: @SathishKrishnan It should not become negative, because one is integrating the squareroot expression of my answer right after "you are integrating". The thing under that radical is a sum of two squares, so it is nonnegative, and the squareroot of a nonnegative is again nonnegtive.

Comment: @SatishKrishnan On second thought maybe your question in previous comment was about what I called $t_1$ in the answer being negative, which of course one does not want. In the four quadrants it is important to choose the appropriate value for $t_1$ in that quadrant. So first we need to worry about $a/b \tan \theta$ which may need to be adjusted according to quadrant, and then use the appropriate choice for the $t_1$ so it comes out in that quadrant.

Comment: @ja72 --> The angle for each t is arctan(tan t * a / b), you got the a / b inverted.

Comment: @GarciadelCastillo $$\theta = \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{y}{x} \right) = \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{b \sin(t)}{a \cos(t)} \right) = \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{b}{a} \tan(t) \right)$$

Comment: @Lubin What approaches could there be other than the numerical approach?

Comment: Sorry, @user56202 , the theoretical approach to this is not my meat.

Answer (score 14):

You can compute this as

$$d=b\,E\bigl(\tan^{-1}(a/b\,\tan(\theta))\,\big|\,1-(a/b)^2\bigr)$$

using the [incomplete elliptic integral of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Incomplete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind) $E(\varphi\,|\,m)$. In Mathematica-Syntax (and suitable for [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2.23*EllipticE%5BArcTan%5B3.05%2F2.23*Tan%5B50%C2%B0%5D%5D%2C1-%283.05%2F2.23%29%5E2%5D)) this can be written as

```
2.23*EllipticE[ArcTan[3.05/2.23*Tan[50°]],1-(3.05/2.23)^2]
```

I adapted this from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/436125/35416) which investigates the converse problem (given arc length, find angle) but along the way treats this direction of the problem as well. As noted there, this angle conversion will only work for the first and last quadrant. Otherwise, either adjust the angle or look at that post for an alternative formula to use in its place.

With a few more digits of precision, the answer is returned as $2.5314195265536624417$ which essentially matches both the other answers here. Of course, printing that many digits in the answer is very bad style if the input is only given to two decimals. It does show that the numerical integration by Jyrki is a bit less precise than what coffeemath did, but even he should theoretically have rounded in the other direction.

Note that the formula above only works for $-\frac\pi2<\theta<\frac\pi2$. For $\frac\pi2<\theta<\pi$ the result of $\tan^{-1}$ will represent $\theta-\pi$ so to correct for that you can add $\pi$ to that result. Similar for $-\pi<\theta<-\frac\pi2$ where you need to subtract $\pi$ from the $\tan^{-1}$ result. Generally speaking you want the first input to the $E$ function to be an angle in the same quadrant as $\theta$, adding integer multiples of $\pi$ as necessary.

Comment: when angle belongs to $[\pi/2,\pi]$, $d$ becomes negative..

Comment: You are right @chloehj, I've updated my answer to discuss the required quadrant adjustments.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

Giving a Mathematica calculation. Same result as coffeemath (+1)

```
In[1]:= ArcTan[3.05*Tan[5Pi/18]/2.23]
Out[1]= 1.02051
In[2]:= x=3.05 Cos[t];
In[3]:= y=2.23 Sin[t];
In[4]:= NIntegrate[Sqrt[D[x,t]^2+D[y,t]^2],{t,0,1.02051}]
Out[4]= 2.53143
```

Comment: Can you give me the full explain from the begin ?

Comment: The first command calculates the value of the parameter $t$ (see Coffeemath's answer) that gives you the point on the ellipse at 50 degree angle. Then I define the functions $x$ and $y$. Then my fourth command (In[4]) tells Mathematica to calculate the value of the integral that gives the arc length (numerically as that is the only way). It spews out $2.5314$. See [this Wikipedia-article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length) for the theory - the paragraph titled "Finding arc lengths by integrating" has this formula.

Comment: By formula I mean
$$L=\int_{t=0}^{1.02051}\sqrt{x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2}\,dt.$$

Comment: Finally I understood it.Thank you very very very much JyrkiLahtonen also Thanks to coffeemath but first of all Thanks to <3 **Allah** <3 .

Comment: Glad to hear that you understand, @Mohammad. Well done.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: The solution becomes negative for angles larger than 90 degrees. Can you help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found this asymptotic approximation from Jacobi's elliptical integral of the second kind some time ago. It's not precise, but converges exactly for degenerate cases of $b=0$ (lines) and $b=a$ (circles). The infinite series methods are ideal where precision is desired. I offer this only as a curiosity. The last term, recently added, contributes little, but ensures convergence for circles. Assume $0\le b\le a$. Then
$$
s\approx 2 \pi \sqrt{a b}+(4 a)^{\frac{a-b}{a+b}} -a^{b-a}.
$$