# Problem about an ellipse distance between two distance in another view

Tags: geometry, arc-length, elliptic-integrals

I have just solved the problem the distance between two points on the circumference of an ellipse following the outer curve after I  read the following article.

[Is it possible to find the distance between two points on the circumference of an ellipse following the outer curve?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2349022/is-it-possible-to-find-the-distance-between-two-points-on-the-circumference-of-a)

Then I want to solve this problem in another view.

Please watch the example below which link of a question of the owner I have pasted above.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwpzv.png)
←here

This ellipse's equation is $\frac{x^2}{2^2} + \frac{y^2}{1^2} = 1$ (Just what original question has mentioned).

So my question is, suppose we know arc-length between two points $x_A$ and $x_B$ and we know Coordinate of $x_A$, how to calculate coordinate of $x_B$？If this solution is impossible, we can assume that $x_A$ = (0, 1).In this case, the equation has very strong Symmetry, so I think we can solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can calculate the coordinates of the other point. 
If you are trying to solve the strength using integrals with a single variable then you have upper and lower bounds. Since you know the limit of one bound you can solve the other bound.

Comment: Both  $x_A$ and $x_B$ are located at first quadrant or $x_A = (1, 0)$ and  $x_B$ is located at first quadrant.

Comment: So what do you mean？ Is there a formula to solve this problem？